# How do you add beveled circled to flat planes?

Tags: bevel

I have a flat plane that I added some width to, and it's going on a machine. The plane will need four screws in all four corners.

What's the best way to do that in 2.82a?

I thought about just making one screw top, and duplicating it three times, inserting into each of the four corners on the plane and grouping/parenting.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Hi, welcome! I can't understand what "and it's going on a machine" means, can you add more details and/or some image to clarify what you mean? I'm sure it will help others to understand and help you better...

Answer (score 0):

[plate_with_beveled_holes](https://gfycat.com/quickvacantamericanavocet)

Welcome!  I believe I understand your question.  Please see above link.

The idea here is to think about the mirror modifier.  As such, I started with a plane situated in the upper right quadrant (in Top View).
Then, add some extra geometry to your plane (it helps with the hole that's coming).

Pick a vertex and snap your 3D cursor there, so you can add a Circle.

Select the circle, then the plane, then go into Edit Mode.  Pick Knife Project to cut a hole on the plane.  The Circle can now be deleted.

Deleting the faces inside the circle leaves you with a hole!  Extrude the plane a bit, then select the edges of the hole and Ctrl-B to bevel it.

Now for the Mirror Modifier.  The key to understanding this modifier is that it mirrors around the Origin.  That's why you see me placing the 3D cursor and changing the object's Origin- I'm controlling where the mirroring happens.

Good luck!